# Prevent TeamCity builds running out-of-hours?

Tags: teamcity

I have some builds that I do NOT want to run out of business hours (they are integration tests that depend on a third party system that is unavailable overnight). Can TeamCity be configured to only run certain builds at certain times, or rather NOT run a build between 10pm and 8.30am?

It looks like I might be able to write a plugin to do this using the StartBuildPrecondition hook, but I was wondering if this existed already?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 4):

A basic solution for this would be to use the [Schedule Trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers), which allows you to specify times of day for the build to execute.

By setting the build to execute on a frequent basis during the day, but only when changes are made, you'd get the appearance of a continuous integration build triggered by VCS changes.

Example Schedule Trigger that executes every 5 minutes between 8:00 AM and 10:00 PM:

- Trigger build: advanced (cron expression)
- Seconds: 0
- Minutes: 0/5
- Hours: 8-22
- Day of month: *
- Month: *
- Day of week: ?
- Year: *
- Enable "Trigger build only if there are pending changes"

Comment: However, this is not the same thing as preventing a build from running. Someone can still press the Run button.

Comment: Correct - it's a workaround.  Separately, it _is_ possible to not allow users to use the run build button by removing the "Run Build" permission.

Comment: Hi, any news on this question? As I am also interested in described solution

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add a build step that just checks the time and exits with an error (e.g. via shell script).

Note that this won't technically stop the build from running, but it can prevent it from doing anything past that if the next build steps are configured to stop on error.